# Where is my mistake (I need to find the total area of a half-trapezoid, half-triangle)?

Tags: geometry

Brilliant wants me to find the total area of the figure (ABCDE). I found it, but it doesn't have such an option. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: What is given in this problem?

Comment: How did you get that $2(2AF + BC) = AE + ED$? It's actually correct and simple to prove with trigonometry but it doesn't look like you're using it.

Comment: @user AB=CD=3, BAD=CDA=DAE=ADE=60°, P(ABCDE)=18

Comment: @caedmon I'm not sure I understand you. I first found AF and BF, then, given that I know the perimeter, I got BC, then I calculated areas of the figures comprising ABCDE, then I added them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, good job! You got a lot right here. Everything up to the area of $FBCH$ is correct. You're only mistake is with the area of triangle $ABF$. The formula is: $\frac{B*H}{2}$. So plugging in the values of the base and height you found earlier: $A= \frac{1.5*1.5\sqrt3}{2}$. This simplifies to $\frac{9\sqrt3}{8}$ and multiplying by $2$ for the triangle on the other side gives us: $\frac{9\sqrt3}{4}$ or $2.25\sqrt3$. Lastly for triangle $ADE$, you are spot on, well done! Adding all these values gives us: $11.5\sqrt3 \approx 19.919$. Tell me if that matches the result you are supposed to have.

Comment: Beyond the well written answer, I appreciate the encouragements you give.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks Jean. I liked that he showed a lot of work and effort, and I thought he deserved to know what mistake he made.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right. I don't know why I made that silly mistake. My best guess is that I recalled that I already multiplied 1.5 and 1.5 when I calculated BF but took a wrong number, 6.75 (which is 2.5 × 2.5 actually) and not 2.25. Yes, it has such an option, only it's written as (23√3)/2

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**Your computation of the area of little triangle $ABF$ is erroneous.**

Let $x=BC=FG$. You have found $AB=3$ by Pythagoras.

As $AD=1.5+x+1.5=3+x=AE=DE$, we can express the perimeter of  this figure:

[image]

in two ways
:

$$2(x+3)+x+6=18 \implies x=2$$

As the area of an equilateral triangle with side $a$ is $a^2\sqrt{3}/4$, the total area is

$$areatriangle(ADE) + areatriangle(ABF+CDG) + arearectangle(BCGF)= $$

$$=5^2 \sqrt{3}/4+3^2 \sqrt{3}/4+2 *  
3 \sqrt{3}/2 = \dfrac{23}{2}\sqrt{3}=11.5 \sqrt{3} $$

which differs from your result.

Comment: Any comment ? It would be good next time to write down your equations in Latex like this `$\sqrt{3}$` or `$MA=\frac{2}{3}$` (all formulas are between dollar signs);  it can be tedious on the first time but once you get accustomed, you can do it quickly Besides, learn how to use Geogebra and/or Desmos for drawing your graphics (it has taken me less than 10 minutes to draw it, using "Paint" to add the text "x,3+x," etc...).